# any work-around on windows 7 for windows Phone 8 apps development

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, mobile-application

I new to Windows 8 Mobile app development and my development laptop has 8 GB RAM and Windows 7 64-bit OS with VS 2012.
Now to develop Windows Phone 8 mobile app do i need to install windows 8 OS on my laptop or i can continue using the same OS.
I read somewhere that Windows 8 OS is must for Windows Phone 8 apps or is there any work-around to continue with same OS.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The only "workaround" would be using Windows 8.1 in a virtual machine like.